# ngModel behaving strangely

Tags: angular

### [Link to the Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4I4s2Wi2F3x8xWVjzgID?p=preview)

There is a parent-child relationship between two components app component `App` and `IndividualComponent`. When I am changing the type of one `teamMember` in the child component, the radio buttons in other places are also getting updated.

Please tell me where I am understanding wrong and how to correct my code.

Below is the entire code involving both components:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, Input} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li [ngClass]="{'list-group-item':true}" *ngFor="let teamMember of teamMembers">
        <div [ngClass]="{'bg-green':teamMember.type==='Good','bg-red':teamMember.type==='Bad'}">
          <app-individual [teamMember]="teamMember"></app-individual>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class App {
  teamMembers: Array<{ name: string, type: 'Good' | 'Bad' }>;
  constructor() {
    this.teamMembers = new Array();
    this.teamMembers.push({ name: 'Member 1', type: 'Good' });
    this.teamMembers.push({ name: 'Member 2', type: 'Good' });
    this.teamMembers.push({ name: 'Member 3', type: 'Good' });
    this.teamMembers.push({ name: 'Member 4', type: 'Good' });
    this.teamMembers.push({ name: 'Member 5', type: 'Good' });
    this.teamMembers.push({ name: 'Member 6', type: 'Good' });
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-individual',
  template:`
  <h3>{{teamMember.name}} -- {{teamMember.type}}</h3>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="teamMember.type" [value]="'Good'"> Good
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="teamMember.type" [value]="'Bad'"> Bad
  </label>
</div>
  `;
})
export class IndividualComponent  {

  constructor() { }
  @Input() teamMember;

}


@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App, IndividualComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply forgot to set the name of your inputs.

Just add `[name]="teamMember.name"`, and it [will work fine](https://plnkr.co/edit/64YrXwhcpLVxDWuyiG9Q?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

The radio buttons need to have a unique `name` property.

If you add `name="{{teamMember.name}}` (or `[name]="teamMember.name` to both of your `<input type="radio" ...>` it should work again.